# What's the best method for emptying an option created with the Settings API?

Tags: plugin-development, options, admin-menu, settings-api

I'm trying to empty an option created with the Settings API and failing.

`update_option ( 'my_option', '' );` appears to do nothing, whereas `delete_option ( 'my_option' );` destroys the whole option causing other problems. I just want to empty the values and reset it.

I'm really clueless how to implement this correctly. Can anyone help? 50 point bounty up for grabs!

```
<?php
//Create the menus
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'tccl_menu' );
function tccl_menu() {  
    //add_menu_page: $page_title; $menu_title, $capability, $menu_slug, $function, $icon_url, $position
    add_menu_page( 'Control', 'Control', 'manage_options', 'tccl-main', 'tccl_menu_page_main', plugins_url( '/traffic-control/images/wp-icon.png' ), '2.2' );
    //add_submenu_page: $parent_slug, $page_title, $menu_title, $capability, $menu_slug, $function
    add_submenu_page( 'tccl-main', 'Domains', 'Domains', 'manage_options', 'tccl-domains', 'tccl_menu_page_domains' ); 
}

//Menu callback functions for drawing pages
function tccl_menu_page_main() {
    ?>
    <div class="wrap">
    <h2>Control</h2>
    <form action="options.php" method="post">
    <?php settings_fields( 'tccl_settings_main' ); ?>
    <?php do_settings_sections( 'tccl_settings_main' ); ?>
    <input name="Submit" type="submit" value="Save Changes" class="button-primary" />
    </form></div>
    <?php
}
function tccl_menu_page_domains() {
    $tccl_domains = get_option( 'tccl_settings_domains' );
    if ( $_POST['trigger'] ) {
        $p_delete_all = $_POST['delete_all'];
        $p_ids = $_POST['ids']; #Get IDs
        $p_deletes = $_POST['deletes']; #Get deletes
        if ( $p_delete_all ) {
            //unset( $tccl_domains );
            //delete_option( 'tccl_settings_domains' );
            foreach( $tccl_domains as $option ) {
                $option = false;
            }
            $tccl_domains = array ();
            update_option( 'tccl_settings_domains', $tccl_domains );
        } elseif ( is_array( $p_ids) ){
            foreach ( $p_ids as $id ) {
                if ( $p_deletes[$id] ) {
                    //unset( $tccl_domains[$id] );
                }
            }
        }
    }
    ?>
    <div class="wrap">
    <?php screen_icon( 'themes' ); ?>
    <h2>Control</h2>
    <form action="options.php" method="post">
    <?php settings_fields( 'tccl_settings_domains' ); ?>
    <?php do_settings_sections( 'tccl_settings_domains' ); ?>
    <input name="Add" type="submit" value="Add Domains" class="button-primary" />
    </form>
    <form action="" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="trigger" value="1">
    <h3>Live Domains</h3>
    <table class="widefat">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><input type="checkbox" name="delete_all" value="1"></th>
            <th>Domain Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th><input type="checkbox" name="delete_all" value="1"></th>
            <th>Domain Name</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody>
        <?php
            print_r ( $tccl_domains );
            if ( is_array( $tccl_domains ) ) {
                foreach ( $tccl_domains as &$value ) {
                    echo '<tr><td><input class="large-text" type="checkbox"></td><td>'.$value['text_area'].'</td></tr>';
                }
            } else {
                echo '<tr><td colspan="2">No domains entered. Use the form above to add domains to this list.</td></tr>';
            }
        ?>
    </tbody>
    </table>
    <br />
    <input name="Delete" type="submit" value="Delete Domains" class="button-secondary" />
    </form>
    <script>
        jQuery('input[name=delete_all]').click(function () {
            if (jQuery(this).is(':checked')) {
            jQuery('tbody input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
                jQuery(this).attr('checked', true);
            });
            jQuery('input[name=delete_all]').attr('checked', true);
            } else {
            jQuery('tbody input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
                jQuery(this).attr('checked', false);
            });
            jQuery('input[name=delete_all]').attr('checked', false);
            }
        });
    </script>
    </div>
    <?php
}

//Settings
add_action( 'admin_init', 'tccl_admin_init' );
function tccl_admin_init() {
    // register_setting: $option_group, $option_name, $sanitize_callback
    register_setting( 'tccl_settings_main', 'tccl_settings_main', 'tccl_settings_main_validate' );
    register_setting( 'tccl_settings_domains', 'tccl_settings_domains', 'tccl_settings_domains_validate' );
    // add_settings_section: $id, $title, $callbak, $page
    add_settings_section( 'tccl_sections_main', 'Main Settings', 'tccl_sections_main_text', 'tccl_settings_main' );
    add_settings_section( 'tccl_sections_domains', 'Add Domains', 'tccl_sections_main_text', 'tccl_settings_domains' );
    // add_settings_field: $id, $title, $callback, $page, $section, $args
    add_settings_field( 'tccl_fields_main_input', 'Enter text here...', 'tccl_fields_main_input', 'tccl_settings_main', 'tccl_sections_main' );
    add_settings_field( 'tccl_fields_domains_input', 'Add domains to the list below. Multiple domains should be seperated by commas.', 'tccl_fields_domains_input', 'tccl_settings_domains', 'tccl_sections_domains' );
}

//Sections callback functions
function tccl_sections_main_text() {
    echo '<p>Enter your settings for the main options in the main section...</p>';
}

//Field callback functions
function tccl_fields_main_input() {
    //Get option 'text_string' value from the database
    $options = get_option( 'tccl_settings_main' );
    $text_string = $options['text_string'];
    //Echo the field
    echo "<input id='text_string' name='tccl_settings_main[text_string]' type='text' value='$text_string' />";
}
function tccl_fields_domains_input() {
    //Get option 'text_string' value from the database
    $options = get_option( 'tccl_settings_domains' );
    $text_area = $options['text_area'];
    //Echo the field
    echo "<textarea id='text_area' name='tccl_settings_domains[text_area]'>$text_area</textarea>";
}

//Settings callback functions (validation)
function tccl_settings_main_validate( $input ) {
    $valid['text_string'] = preg_replace( '/[^a-zA-Z]/', '', $input['text_string'] );

    if ( $valid['text_string'] != $input['text_string'] ) {
        //add_setting_error: $title, $id, $error_message, $class
        add_settings_error( 'tccl_fields_main_input', 'tccl_texterror', 'Incorrect value entered!', 'error' );
    }   

    return $valid;
}
function tccl_settings_domains_validate( $input ) {
    $options = get_option( 'tccl_settings_domains' );
    $options[] = $input;
    return $options;
}
?>
```

Comment: I use that function all the time, where are you making that call to `update_option`, can i see more of your code? Ideally the code for the function it's sitting inside if it's sat inside a function.. (and if it's hooked onto something, details about what it's hooked onto would help to).

Comment: I'm calling it from inside an `add_submenu_page` callback function.

Comment: Is the usual value of the option a string or an array? Do you have several options?

Comment: An array, I think a multi-dimensional one. Do I need to reset it with a new array?

Comment: why not set the array with your default options? and what kind of problems is it causing?

Comment: Is there any code that runs after that call that interacts with the option/data? Note: It wouldn't hurt to update it with an empty array, since you're dealing with an array of values when interacting with the option otherwise..

Comment: Tried updating with an empty array, I think `update_option` will just keep adding new values. Having more success with `delete_option` and `add_option`...

Comment: If we could see how exactly you're using this code it might be easier to see the problem, based on what you've posted there shouldn't be an issue(why not pastebin your code?).

Comment: I've got `delete_option` working now. Will update question with code now...

Comment: As I originally thought `delete_option` is causing more problems than it solves. I've updated the code in the question as I'm still totally stuck on this...

Comment: Why are you calling `register_setting()` twice, with only one setting added to each array?

Comment: Good question. I thought to set up separate settings for each page. Unnecessary?

Comment: Hey Chip, where did you go?

Comment: Just a suggestion trnsfrmr, code with debug mode on.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you wrote your code correctly, then delete_option would be the correct way. The question isn't how to clear the option; the question is how to structure your code such that the "option does not exist" case is a valid case.

Think about it. The first time you start this code, that option isn't going to exist at all, right? Your code should be perfectly capable of handling that case, since it's the first thing the user is ever going to see.

get_option() accepts a default value if the option does not exist. So use that. If you had an empty array for the default, for example, you'd have code like this:

```
$options = get_option('whatever',array());
```

Assuming you're using the settings API, then you should use the `isset` function in if statements to account for the missing-field case. Something like this:

```
if (!isset($options['name'])) {
//... the option isn't set to something 
} else {
//... the option is set to something
}
```

And handle each case of actual *use* of the option accordingly.

Comment: This is actually an answer to a *second* question, that @trnsfmr should probably split out from the original question, into one of its own.

Comment: FYI: Your comments in the isset example are round the wrong way.

Comment: I'm struggling to understand how to make this answer work in my code. I think I should go back to the drawing board, thinking about using Chips post on the Settings API to work from.

Comment: @trnsfrmr: The bottom line is that you need to do a delete_option and then fix whatever errors you get from having no option set at all. Because the very first time somebody runs your code, no option will be set.

Comment: OK, delete option is working, but have failed on some other stuff. Time for a new question as Chip suggests. Hopefully you guys will still have some patience left... :)

Answer (score 4):

Do you want to unset *just one option*, or do you want to unset *every option in the array*?

If it's the former:

```
$tccl_domains = get_option( 'tccl_settings_domains' );

$tccl_domains['option_to_unset'] = false;

update_option( 'tccl_settings_domains', $tccl_domains );
```

If it's the latter:

```
$tccl_domains = get_option( 'tccl_settings_domains' );

foreach( $tccl_domains as $option ) {
    $option = false;
}
update_option( 'tccl_settings_domains', $tccl_domains );
```

Comment: Working on the latter, but `update_option` still seems to add more options rather than overwrite the existing...

Comment: *`update_option` still seems to add more options rather than overwrite the existing*... I don't understand what you mean; can you clarify?

Comment: Everytime `update_option` runs my array seems to get bigger. I'm wondering if my settings registration code is correct, I've added it to the question above...

Comment: Would it be possible to post your *entire* settings-related code, either in your question, or in a Pastebin, or something? Trying to track down an issue like this would be much easier if we can see the entire code, in context.

Comment: Let me see if I can clean it up and link it...

Comment: I've updated with the full admin screen code...

Comment: Hey Chip, I posted the full code yesterday, does that help?

Answer (score 0):

first off, understand that every time you do a call to `update_option()` and `delete_option()` - not sure about `delete_option()` though - the validation function is called. And the way `tccl_settings_domains_validate()` is validating is what's causing the `update_option()` function to add more options:

```
 function tccl_settings_domains_validate( $input ) {
   $options = get_option( 'tccl_settings_domains' );
   $options[] = $input;
   return $options;
 }
```

what this function is doing is to take whatever is inside *tccl_settings_domains* and assign it to `$options`:

`$options = get_option('tccl_settings_domains');`

then add/push whatever is in `$input` into `$options` array. When the function returns `$options` (which basically "saves" the option) what's saved are the contents of options field **plus** the value of `$input`. Thus, the array gets bigger.

So, try this for a start:

```
function tccl_settings_domains_validate( $input ) {
    if( isset( $input['action'] ) && $input['action'] == 'add-domain' ){
        //add new value to $options array
        options = get_option( 'tccl_settings_domains' );
        $options[] = $input;
        return $options;
    }
    //return whatever value is passed.
    return $input;
}
```

then, in the Add Domain form (one that goes to options.php), add this hidden input `<input name="tccl_settings_domains[action]" type="hidden" value="add-domain" />`

This is the most straightforward solution I could think of that involves minimum amount of change in your code.

let me know if that works for you =)

Comment: Typo on line 4, should be $options...

Comment: I'm afraid I can't get your suggestion to work. The if statement doesn't seem to ever be true.

Comment: Also, from what I'm seeing the validation callback does not appear to run on `delete_options()`.